# Creating your own LightDmGreeter

Tags: compiling, lightdm

I would like to create my own LightDm Greeter for Ubuntu 18.04. As I would like to put a process in the background that will constantly poll a camera to detect a user, that will allow user to log in automatically.

I was able to implement this by configuring PAM.d and using GDM but somehow I need to create it in such away that I dont have to choose user to activate face detection.

But my main strugle in LightDm Greeter is how to setup development environment and compiling.
First I tried to build:
https://github.com/Xubuntu/lightdm-gtk-greeter
First: I run autogen.sh, then I run make but after that, I dont know what to do already for the build to be reflected in my machine. I tried to run the install-sh but it seem it needs an argument. So I want to ask procedure how to deploy it properly in ubuntu 18.04?

Also I found this:
http://people.ubuntu.com/%7Erobert-ancell/lightdm/reference/LightDMGreeter.html
I was excited to create my own greeter from scratch, but i encounter many problem such as:
It cannot find headers such as lightdm.h, glib.h and glib-conf.h, I was able to remove the compile error by:

```
 gcc main.c -I/usr/include/lightdm-gobject-1 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -
I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -o main
```

but I ended up on another error:

```
main.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `g_main_loop_new'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I would like to seek for help or advice how to setup development environment properly for light dm greeter.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: If you are asking this question because you want facial recognition for authentication and login (and developing your own application is not your primary goal) then you may want to consider installing Howdy (https://github.com/Boltgolt/howdy).

Comment: Just re-read your question... I see you *need* to code your own application because you don't want to "have to choose user to activate face detection".

Answer (score 0):

For those who will have same problem with me, i found the solution here:
https://github.com/Xubuntu/lightdm-gtk-greeter/blob/master/.github/workflows/distcheck.yml

it listed all the dependency it need, just do each steps indicated.
The one thing I encountered that it is not in the list is an error upon running the autogen.sh.. it cannot find autopoint

so i search the web and run: sudo apt-get install autopoint

its from:
https://dausruddin.com/autoreconf-failed-to-run-autopoint-no-such-file-or-directory/

---

from now, my next step is to find out how to deploy my changes in the codes to may machine. If anyone has idea, please help.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Hi there. Did you find anyway to run/test your changes?